# AngularJS Advanced $resource Mapping

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-resource, angularjs-factory

How can I use AngularJS $resource for more advanced API requests? I need to request the following urls:

> /schools/
>
> /schools/1
>
> /schools/1/books
>
> /school/1/books/1

For basic urls like:

> /schools/
>
> /schools/1

I know i can do:

```
angular.module('resources.schools').factory('School', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/schools/:id');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go ahead and nest the URL and give the parent identifier the name of the field on your model:

```
$resource("/schools/:school_id/books/:id")
```

Comment: I want to use the same factory for both requests. Like, School.query(), and School.getBooks()

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question and your latest comment, turn the 'books' portion into a parameter (e.g. 'controller') then extend the resource with a method that sets the controller.

```
var School = $resource("/schools/:school_id/:controller/:book_id", {}, {
  getBooks: {
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
        controller: 'books'
    } 
  }
});
```

Now you can achieve the following:

```
var schools = School.query();
var newSchool = new School();
var mySchool = School.get(1);
var mySchoolBooks = mySchool.getBooks();
var aBookInMySchool = School.query({'school_id':1, controller:'books', 'book_id': 2})
```